# Проблема с отступами в html

Tags: html, css

Есть параграф, которому хочу сделать отступ внутри синего листа с помощью margin. Изначально, все выглядит так:

[image: изначально]

После изменений:

[image: после правок]

Почему он затрагивает весь лист? Мне нужно, что бы он только делал отступ для параграфа.

Мой код:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.content {
  width: 960px;
  height: 1500px;
  background: #a7cae6;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
#paragraph {
  width: 420px;
  height: auto;
}
body {
  background-position: 132px 132px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <img src="img/header2.png" class="img-responsive">
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <p id="paragraph">Элмо Кеннеди О'Коннор,известный как
      <br>Bones — парень, который менее, чем
      <br>за год, стал легендой андеграунд рэпа.
      <br>Родился 11 января 1994 года в
      <br>Мьюир Бич, штат Калифорния. В 7 лет
      <br>переехал с родителями в Хауэлл, штат
      <br>Мичиган, где жил до 16 лет.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: приведите пожалуйста весь код в вопросе, а не в скриншотах. Ну или в фидле хотя бы.

Answer (score 2):

`margin` - это внешний отступ

`padding` - это внутренний

**по этому у вас такая бяка получается**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.content {
  width: 960px;
  min-height: 150px;
  background: #a7cae6;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 13px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
#paragraph {
  width: 370px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: auto;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <img src="http://obsudi.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/1446484549-658.jpg" class="img-responsive">
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <p id="paragraph">Элмо Кеннеди О'Коннор,известный как Bones — парень, который менее, чем за год, стал легендой андеграунд рэпа. Родился 11 января 1994 года в Мьюир Бич, штат Калифорния. В 7 лет переехал с родителями в Хауэлл, штат Мичиган, где жил до 16 лет.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://archive.oreilly.com/oreillyschool/courses/htmlcss/html5/images/CSSBoxDiagram.png

Answer (score 0):

Это классика

Сначала про схлопывание отсупов. 
Этот эффект наблюдается, когда у блочных элементов расположенных рядом друг с другом по вертикали, отступы не суммируются, а объединяются между собой. Само схлопывание действует на два и более блока (один может быть вложен внутрь другого) с отступами сверху или снизу, при этом примыкающие отступы комбинируются в один. Этот эффект работает только для блоков, у которых не заданы поля и границы. Для отступов слева и справа схлопывание никогда не применяется.

Несмотря на загадочность, схлопывание несёт в себе сугубо практическое значение и в первую очередь предназначено для корректного отображения текста. Расстояние между абзацами (тег `<p>`) без схлопывания увеличится в два раза, тогда как верхний отступ первого абзаца и нижний отступ последнего абзаца останутся неизменными. Схлопывание гарантирует, что расстояние в абзацах везде будет одинаковым.

Правила вычисления единого отступа меняются в зависимости от ряда условий, так, есть разница между положительным и отрицательным значением отступа, родительским и дочерним элементом.

То что у вас.
Предположим, что в нижнем блоке располагается дочерний элемент, у которого задан верхний отступ. Из блочной модели следует, что такой отступ сдвигает дочерний элемент вниз относительно верхнего края родителя. Однако с учётом схлопывающихся отступов результат будет иным. Отступ словно выйдет за пределы блока и будет задавать расстояние между верхним блоком и родительским элементом

Answer (score -1):

Потому что [margin collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

Как вариант, можно добавить `border` контенту.